# App accelerometer behaves differently when plugged into Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, core-motion

Working on game where you move ship by titling screen.
Using Landscape right mode.

If device not flat the ship moves so i needed to calibrate the Y tilt when the app is run so that is neutral up/down movement.

I got it to work by reading the tilt when app was run and making that neutral.

Anyway, it works fine (took me hours to figure it out but I did it!)
It works great when I have my iPhone plugged in to MacBook and run it through Xcode.

But if I run it when the phone is not connected to Xcode - it does not work.

It acts like the calibration I set up was not even there.

I set it up to catch the Y tilt angle when you launch the app "view did load".

Works great when plugged in but not when not plugged to Xcode.
I tried force quit-relaunch, even reset phone and launch app again.

Comment: Do you happen to have print statements that (may) slow down your calibration/correction logic and affect it? No matter what, post the code because a written statement saying 'it doesn't work' doesn't help much.

Comment: Yeah, I actually have a bunch of print statements that I used for figuring it out. I will try commenting them out. Will post code if that does not work just didnt want to post a bunch of code if it was something simple. appreciate it.LOL I am sure there is a better way than I used to figure this out